# Finding multiples of integers quickly

Tags: c++, arrays

I've written out this particular code in C++ to try and find out all the multiples of the integers 3 & 5 below 1000 by using a while loop and then storing it in integer arrays. I also want to print each of those multiples out. But every time I debug this program, it endlessly prints out '0'. I just don't understand. Can someone please explain how to correct this code and why that unusual output occurs?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const int three_limit = 334;
   const int five_limit = 200;
   int threeArray[three_limit] = {0};
   int fiveArray[five_limit] = {0};
   int i = 1, j = 1;
   while (i < three_limit)
   {
      int multiples = 3*i;
      multiples = threeArray[i - 1];
      cout << threeArray[i - 1] << endl;
      i++;
   }
   while (j < five_limit)
   {
      int multiples = 5*i;
      multiples = fiveArray[j - 1];
      cout << fiveArray[j - 1] << endl;
      j++;
   }
   char response;
   cin >> response;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the order of the operator `=`.

Comment: In `multiples = threeArray[i - 1];` and `multiples = fiveArray[j - 1];` you are apparently trying to assign from left to right. Assignment works from right to left. Plus, tag this question as homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output will have duplicates when the number contains multiples of 3 and 5, e.g. 15, 30.

Some of the suggestions use multiplication or mod (%) which are quite slow, but there's a much faster solution using a binary array that will also help you avoid the duplication problem. Something like:

```
int main() {
    bool nums[1001];
    for(int i = 1; i < 1001; ++i)
        nums[i] = 0;

    for(int i = 3; i < 1001; i += 3)
        nums[i] = 1;
    for(int i = 5; i < 1001; i += 5)
        nums[i] = 1;

    for(int i = 1; i < 1001; ++i)
        if(nums[i])
            cout << i << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
threeArray[i - 1] = multiples;
```

instead of

```
multiples = threeArray[i - 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

See the following code, to generate multiples of 5

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
int max=1000;
int i=1,result=0;



while(result!=max && i!=200)
{
    result=5*i;                    // change the 5 by 3 for multiples of 3
    printf("\n %d",result);
    i++;

}       

}
```

Comment: the i variable is the limiter in your case!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this

```
multiples = threeArray[i - 1];
```

should really be

```
threeArray[i - 1] = multiples;
```

Try debugging it again and watch `multiples` while executing this line.

Answer (score 0):

```
multiples = threeArray[i - 1];
```

You're overwriting the local int with the (empty) contents of the array - you have your assignment the wrong way around.

Answer (score 0):

You never modify the values in your array. It should be something like this:

```
while (i < three_limit)
   {
      int multiples = 3*i;
      threeArray[i-1] = multiples;
      cout << threeArray[i - 1] << endl;
      i++;
   }
```